# How do I get the last updated date of the pdo table

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to get the last updated date by post type but I dont know how to get it by simple query like

```
SELECT updated_at FROM Table WHERE post_type = posts
```

I am attaching the screen shot for my mysql table.

[image: PHPmyadmin]

I want to get last updated post date by post_type.

Comment: Looks like the value you need is not `posts` but `"post"`.  Add an `ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1` and you'll get the latest.

Comment: Thank you it is working like a rocket!! How to accept your answar?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(updated_at)` to get the last value.

Comment: You can upvote comments but there is no answer to be accepted. If no one provides answer, you can write one yourself and accept it.

Comment: not clear why this was closed as not about programming?  voting to reopen